# Using Server Side JavaScript and trying to get the properties of an element on my DOM

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, serverside-javascript, exacttarget

I'm using Server Side JavaScript to interact with our data.  For example:

```
<script runat="server">
        var subscriberScoringHistoryDE = DataExtension.Init("de_name");
        var rows = subscriberScoringHistoryDE.Rows.Retrieve();
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {

        }
</script>
```

The above will run because it's hitting a JS API that's on our server.  So anyways, the above runs fine.  The problem I'm having is if I have something like the below in conjunction with the above:

```
<script>
        var barChartData = {

            // labels will be the dates
            labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
            datasets : [
                {
                    fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                    strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",

                    // data will be the count
                    data : [65,59,90,81,56,55,40]
                },  
            ]
        }

    var myLine = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Bar(barChartData);

    </script>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
</body>
```

The JS code will not see anything called "canvas".  I even tried putting `runat="server"` on my canvas.  I can imagine this is because it's looking at the server for an ID called "canvas" and not my client side DOM, am I correct in assuming this?

**Is it possible to intermingle client-side JavaScript and server-side JavaScript?  How can I get my JavaScript to see the canvas that's on my client COM?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your main script in an `onload` type handler, so it'll only run AFTER the dom has been loaded/parsed. One quick/dirty way of doing it is

```
<script>
   function foo() {
      // your var barchartdata etc... goes here
   }
</script>

<body onload="foo();">
....
</body>
```

If you were using jquery, you'd get a somewhat more reliable

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   /// var barchartdata stuff goes here
});
```

As for mingling the client-/server-side code, not really possible, since they execute in totally different environments. client-side JS code can't directly call on server-side code, and server-side code can't call client-side code, because JS calls cannot pass through an HTTP layer. You COULD use an ajax call to indirectly call things, but then you're still using HTTP.